# Extracting rotation from world transform in Scenekit

Tags: graphics, 3d, scenekit

I want to put an indicator in my app showing which direction an object is facing. I'd like to obtain the rotation in world space to do this but don't know how to extract it from worldTransform. Can someone please tell me how to do this, or is there a better way? I just need rotation in radians on the Y axis from the original position. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SCNNode's have a bunch of options for orientations and worldTransform is part of that structure.  You can also get the nodes orientation/eulerAngles, etc.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408048-orientation

GLKit Functions have conversions for degrees to radians, like:

```
SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat(Float(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90))), y: 0, z: 0, duration: 0)
```

World Transform: CATransForm3D:
init(m11: CGFloat, m12: CGFloat, m13: CGFloat, m14: CGFloat, m21: CGFloat, m22: CGFloat, m23: CGFloat, m24: CGFloat, m31: CGFloat, m32: CGFloat, m33: CGFloat, m34: CGFloat, m41: CGFloat, m42: CGFloat, m43: CGFloat, m44: CGFloat)

These are the rotations

Edit - is it that you need the definitions for transform/worldTransform, matrices... like m11, etc?

```
var nRight: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
var nUp: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
var nScale: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(1, 1, 1)
var nTarget: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    
vNode.transform.m11 = nRight.x
vNode.transform.m12 = nRight.y
vNode.transform.m13 = nRight.z
vNode.transform.m21 = nUp.x
vNode.transform.m22 = nUp.y
vNode.transform.m23 = nUp.z
vNode.transform.m31 = nTarget.x
vNode.transform.m32 = nTarget.y
vNode.transform.m33 = nTarget.z
```

Best guess = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(node.eulerAngule.y) is what you are really looking for.

If it has to come from worldTransform, I "think" it's this, but I'm no math expert:

```
nUp.x = vNode.worldTransform.m21;
nUp.y = vNode.worldTransform.m22;
nUp.z = vNode.worldTransform.m23;
GLKMathDegreesToRadians(nUp);
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to perform a rotation, I'm asking how to obtain the world rotation value for a SCNNode. Given a SCNNode's worldTransform property how to I obtain the rotation vector? I believe that the rotation property on SCNNode is in local space.

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you only want to rotate the Y Axis, to point in the direction of your other node?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already performed the rotation, I'm trying to determine if there is a way to query the current rotation angle in world space without keeping track of it myself.

Comment: @Cliff - please see edit, those are your rotation angles, thx

Comment: Thanks @voltan, I'm not clear on what you are telling me. If I have 
let transform = node.worldTransform
and I want the Y axis rotation in the form
let radians = ...
what would I put there?